# R multilevel mediation with uneven sample sizes in Y and M models

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to run a multilevel mediation analysis in R.
I get the error: Error in mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat = "treat", mediator = mediator, data=data): 
  number of observations do not match between mediator and outcome models

Models M and Y are multilevel lme4 models, and there are uneven sample sizes in these models.  Is there anything I can do to run this analysis?  Will it really only run if I have the same sample sizes in each model?

Answer (score 0):

Fit the model with less observations first (which is, I guess, `model.Y`, because that model has more predictors and thus is more likely to have more missings), then use the model frame from that model as data for the 2nd model:

```
model.M <- lmer(..., data = model.Y@frame)
```

That should work.